# Clipboard c# workbook to Excel and notepad

Tags: c#, excel, clipboard

From my c# application, i want to add text with font to clipboard. 
If i paste it to excel, i want to see it with format and if i paste it to notepad, same result obviously without font.

the issue :

- If i use a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application and create workbook and worksheet, i can feed the clipboard using Clipboard.SetDataObject(wb) where wb is my workbook : The paste function works into excel but nothing is paste into notepad.
- If i use a code like :

  ```
  DataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
  dataObj.SetData(wb);
  dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "myunformattedtext");
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
  ```

It's ok for notepad but excel also retrieve "myunformattedtext" and not wb

I tried to use some Dataformats with dataObj.SetData(wb) like dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf,wb) but i test all available formats in DataFormats and also Formats i can get from a ClipBoard.GetDataObject() using paste from excel (26 possible values) but without positive results.

Is there a dedicated excel workbook format for setdata ? I guess that if the response is no, the best solution is to use an XML Spreadsheet...

Thanks

Comment: uh? your overwriting the clipboard!  You write wb to it, then the text string...the conversion from formatted to unformatted is done on the destination side not the source side.

Comment: can you do something like: `Clipboard.SetDataObject(wb);` `Clipboard.SetDataObject(Clipboard.GetDataObject().SetData(DataFormats.Text, "myunformattedtext"));`

Comment: @cjb110 you mean when i call twice setdata ? no i don't think because if i reverse dataObj.SetData(wb); and
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "myunformattedtext"); the clipboard is still containing myunformattedtext when i try to paste it. it's just if i call ClipBoard.setdata or Clipboard.Setdataobject several time that i overwrite

Comment: @Bolu this code doesn't seem to work since SetData return void and SetDataObject need an argument, is a parenthesis or comma missing ? If you are trying to concatenate Clipboard content i don't think it works and i believe that invoke setdata several time with differents formats is the way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set Clipboard's `DataObject` to `wb` first then get its currect `DataObject` and work from there:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(wb);
DataObject dataObj=new DataObject();

foreach(string format in Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats())
{
    // have a look of its current available Formats, and add anything you feel is necessary.
    // you may need RTF for word for example        

    //this will work with excel 2003 (xls file):
    //if(format.Contains("Biff"))

    //for excel 2007 forwards (xlsx file) you may need to add HTML format:
    if(format==DataFormats.Html||format.Contains("Biff"))
    {
        dataObj.SetData(format, Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(format));
    }
}
//you can set your text data by 
//dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "myunformattedtext"); 
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
```

Comment: Ok i understand what you mean. I made my own loop and call setdata for each dataformat (because i don't know which one are pertinent for excel) except for text cause i want to edit it. I now have a problem of insufficient memory after a few foreach loop, it seems like the solution is to serialize the object but it's getting complicated plus the fact that the double Clipboard.SetDataObject is kind of a hack (because we don't actualy know the needed format). I used XML Spreadsheet for now, thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need all of them, just pick `DataFormats.Rtf` for example

Comment: I already tried DataFormats.Rtf, data and format are ok in Word but not in excel where i only retrieve table data and not format (very strange). Biff gives the same result. As i said in my first post, i tested several format and none of them work. If i need to choose the right combination of them, it can be very long to test. "Biff" is not in DataFormats, same thing for "XML Spreadsheet" with a call to dataObj.SetData("XML Spreadsheet", xmlStream); where xmlStream is a MemoryStream. I think the solution must be something with "Workbook" and perhaps a conversion of wb but can't find it.

Comment: Thanks ! just one thing it's DataFormats.Html and not DataFormats.HTML